# What happens to JS while the browser window is minimised?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

Is it that the JS continues to execute but no HTML is rendered until that browser window/tab is viewed by the user again?

Run the example below, leave the browser window for a few intervals and come back, it will seem as if the something was qeued up? What is it? Why? And can I stop it?

```js
setInterval(updateTiles, 4000);

function updateTiles() {

  var boxes, randomIndex, randomBox;

  boxes = $(".box");

  randomIndex = Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(0, boxes.length));
  randomBox = $(boxes[randomIndex]);

  $(randomBox).toggleClass("flipper");
}

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  margin:10px;
}

.flipper {
  transition: 1.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(360deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: That depends on what browser/version/settings the user has

Comment: @Luca Thought it might be down to browser behaviour, I have tried to find some info on Mozila's docs but all I found was an api to get interact with other windows/tabs.

Comment: I think this is CSS animations,.. They only trigger on document flow, so if you minimize there is no document flow, but your timer is still running and applying animations.

Comment: `setInterval` doesn't que up events.

Comment: @Abs the problem is for the css transition, the browser browsing on other pages will keep in memory the animations until you return on the animated site

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems that, almost in chrome, the CSS Transitions using setInterval are "qeued up",
i had a problem with a clock made in d3, that, after changing the seconds tick in background, caused problems to the browser when reentering the page.

> Qeued up means that ([like you can read here better](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#transition-shorthand-property)) these rules lead to
>   the entire timing function of the new transition being used, rather
>   than jumping into the middle of a timing function, which can create a
>   jarring effect.
>
> One of the major categories of optimizations that implementations can
>   make is implementing animation of certain high-value properties (such
>   as transform and opacity) run on a browser’s compositor thread or
>   process without updating style or layout on the main Web content
>   thread unless up-to-date style data are needed. This optimization
>   often requires allocations of graphics memory to display the contents
>   of the element being animated. Implementations should take care to
>   ensure that Web content cannot trigger unsafe out-of-memory handling
>   by using large numbers of animations or animations on elements
>   covering large areas (where large may be defined in terms of
>   pre-transform or post-transform size).

I solved, checking when the user change the page, and checking when the user reenter the page, starting and stopping the timer.

How you can see, i stop the setTimeout call if my document isn't visible, and i restart function if the document is visible.

```js
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function updateTiles() {
  if(!document.hidden){
    console.log('the function is running');
    var boxes, randomIndex, randomBox;

    boxes = $(".box");

    randomIndex = Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(0, boxes.length));
    randomBox = $(boxes[randomIndex]);

    $(randomBox).toggleClass("flipper");
    setTimeout(updateTiles, 4000);
  }else{
    console.log('stop the function');
  }
}

var restartTimer=function ()  {
        if (!document.hidden) {
            console.log('restart the function');
            updateTiles();
        }
    };

document.removeEventListener('visibilitychange',restartTimer);
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange',restartTimer);

updateTiles();
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  margin:10px;
}

.flipper {
  transition: 1.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(360deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: `the events using setInterval are qeued up`, no. that's not what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout and setInterval will accumulate and run all at once once the window gets focus. For queued animations it looks abrupt and sometimes janky. I recommend using **window.requestAnimationFrame** that is aware of the current window's focus. So animations or functions you provide will not execute.

Comment: Seems like my intuition was wrong , just did: `setInterval(function(){console.log(performance.now())},2000)`. I can confirm regular readings. I guess it still does not change the fact that requestAnimationFrame is the way to go. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here has nothing to do with `setTimeout` etc, they will run just fine at the time you requested even when minimized, nothing is getting queued here.

But what doesn't continue to run are the animations (as that would just be a waste), and as you most likely know CSS animations trigger when the animation class is applied.  So while minimized your .flipper class is still getting changed, but because animations have been paused, they won't trigger until animations are resumed when coming out of minimize state.

Saying all this, doing what Mr.Bruno has suggested of pausing the timer would seem a good idea anyway, why even bother flipping classes when not visible.